# Finding polynomial given output of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand how to find a solution to what appears to be a pretty basic linear algebra problem.

The problem is:

Let
$$
L: R3\to P3 
$$
be a linear transformation with
$$
 L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = 1 + 2x
$$

$$
L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = 5x^2
$$

$$
L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = x - x^2
$$

Find:

$$
L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
$$

Now, I know that as L is a linear transformation,

$$
L(\alpha x) = \alpha L(x)
$$
and
$$
L(\alpha x + \beta y)  = \alpha L(x) + \beta L(x)
$$

At this point, I am not sure where to begin. Do I find the standard matrix representation of the linear transformation and then apply it to
 \begin{smallmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{smallmatrix} ?

Or, am I missing something obvious here? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a\\ b \\ c \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) 
= a \;L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
+b\; L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
+c \; L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

$ \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
= \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
+\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) $

and

$ \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
= \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
-\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) $

so

$ L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
= L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
+L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) = (x-x^2)+5x^2= 4x^2+x $

and

$ \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
= \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
-\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) 
= (1+2x)-(4x^2+x) = -4x^2+x+1 $

so

$L\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a\\ b \\ c \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
=a(-4x^2+x+1)+b(4x^2+x) +c(5x^2)$